# How to remove [ symbol from the string "[ABC]"

Tags: java, arrays

```
String str = "[catch the ball : throw away]"; 
String result = str.replaceAll("[-+[^:,]",""); 
String[] arrOfStr = result.split(":"); 
for (String a : arrOfStr) 
  System.out.println(a);
```

i want to print without [ symbol. please someone help in this.

Comment: Add a double backslash infront of the symbol. Its a reserved letter and needs to be escaped, but you need to escape the backslash in your editor too, hence double backslash

Comment: Line 2 will remove the `:` character, so you can't split on it in line 3.  I think it will do what you want if you remove the `:` character from the `replaceAll` argument

Comment: simply use `str.replace("[", "")`

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is incorrect `[-+[^:,]`. This represents a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), which elements `-+[^:,` should be replaced. However `[` is a special character which indicates the beginning of a class character. So `[` must be followed by `]`, or it must be escaped `\\]`.

- `[` treated as special symbol - begging of a class character
- `\\[` has no special meaning just a `[` character.

In your case the regex should look like

```
"[catch the ball : throw away]".replaceAll("[-+\\[^:,]","")
// produces "catch the ball  throw away]"
```

Please see [Backslashes, escapes, and quoting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bs) section, for more details.

Please also note that `String[] arrOfStr = result.split(":");` is not going to work, since `result` doesn't contain `:`, because it has been replace with empty string using regex `"[-+\\[^:,]",""`

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the special character `]` after two backslashes because the special character `]` alone has a different meaning (e.g. array definition), which is why \ must come before it:

[ = `\\[`

So for your example write this inside, then it removes the square bracket and replace it with nothing (empty, "")

`String result = str.replaceAll("\\[", "")`

Answer (score 0):

```
    String str = "[catch the ball : throw away]"; 
    String result = str.replaceAll("\\[","");
    result = result.replaceAll("\\]",""); 
    String[] arrOfStr = result.split(":"); 
    for (String a : arrOfStr) 
      System.out.println(a);
```

I have removed [ in line 2 and then removed ] in line 3. This will successfully split on : and give the correct result.